Gauge value not updating for a particular pod
I have a dropwizard application where each pod processes multiple requests, and each request has an integer output which I wish to capture using gauge.
Code snippet
MetricRegistry metricRegistry;
public generatemetric(int value){
      
     metricRegistery.gauge(metricName, () -> () -> value);
}

Now the value associated with each pod is not updating.
I am using codehale.metrics library.
